# Mathematical Induction with Inequality Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, induction

Prove that $(\frac{x+y}{2})^n \le \frac{x^n+y^n}{2}$ for $n\ge1$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R^+}$ using induction.

Base case. n=1. $\frac{x+y}{2} \le \frac{x+y}{2}$

Assume true for $n=k \ge 1$.

Then $(\frac{x+y}{2})^k \le \frac{x^k+y^k}{2}$

Show that this holds for $n=k+1$.

Then $(\frac{x+y}{2})^{k+1} \le \frac{x^{k+1}+y^{k+1}}{2} = \frac{x^kx+y^ky}{2}$

L.H.S. = $(\frac{x+y}{2})^k (\frac{x+y}{2}) \le \frac{x^k+y^k}{2}(\frac{x+y}{2}) = \frac{x^kx+y^ky+x^ky+y^kx}{4} = \frac{x+y}{2}[\frac{x^k+y^k}{2}]$

Did I make a mistake? What am I missing?

Comment: In order to conclude the proof you have to show $${x^k+y^k\over 2}{x+y\over 2}\le {x^{k+1}+y^{k+1}\over 2}$$ Multiply the inequality by $4$ and subtract. You should get $(x^k-y^k)(x-y)\ge 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to proving the inequality! To finish off you just need to show that
$$\frac{x^kx+y^ky+x^ky+y^kx}4=\frac{x^{k+1}+y^{k+1}+x^ky+y^kx}4\le \frac{x^{k+1}+y^{k+1}}2$$
To do so you should notice that

> you have similar quantities on both sides, so it is actually enough to show that $\frac{x^ky+y^kx}4\le \frac{x^{k+1}+y^{k+1}}4$ or $x^ky+y^kx\le x^{k+1}+y^{k+1}$

and then

> $(x^k-y^k)(x-y)\ge 0$. Since if $x>y,$ then (because x and y are non-negative) $x^k>y^k.$ So either both $(x^k-y^k)$ and $(x-y)$ are positive or both are negative.